# how to paste data from clipboard to textarea

Tags: java, swing

When I use getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) to paste some text from clipboard like:

```
Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
    String text=null;
    if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
         text= (String) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }
```

I get exception javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid location.
Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/BadLocationException.html):

> attempts to reference a location that doesn't exist.

So you'll have to double-check in the GUI code.

But this appears to be an error within the Swing part, not because of `getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)` itself